# jquery and controller issue with endless page scrolling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I recently implemented endless page scrolling as seen in the [blog post](http://christianvarga.com/2013/02/simple-infinite-scroll-with-rails-and-jquery/). In summary, I show 10 posts on a page, when the user reaches the bottom of the page, the app fires a 'get' request to the index action, loads 10 more posts and appends them to the page with jquery.

Here is my implementation:

post_controller

```
def index
if params[:tags]
  @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tags]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
else
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render 'index.js.erb'}
end
end
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#posts').append('<%= escape_javascript(render @posts) %>');
$('a.load-more-posts').attr('href', '<%= posts_path page: @posts.next_page %>');

<% unless @posts.next_page %>
  $('a.load-more-posts').remove();
<% end %>
```

I run into some issues when I try to filter the posts by tag. The root problem is that the same `index.js.erb` file gets fired when a user manually clicks a tag to see posts with that tag and also by the endless scroll function.

When a new tag is clicked, rather than the posts just be appended to the existing html, the displayed posts should first be cleared and then the new posts should be appended.

From that point it seemed obvious that I should separate out the index action and a separate `posts_tagged_with` action. This action would have its own js file that is very similar, but it will replace html rather than append.

The problem with this is that the original `index.js.erb` is still called when the user scrolls down, which appends posts from index action.

Is there a better implementation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.js.erb you can change your first two line for this:

```
    $('#posts').<%= params[:tags] && params[:page].nil? ? "html" : "append" %>('<%= escape_javascript(render @posts) %>');
    $('a.load-more-posts').attr('href', '<%= posts_path page: @posts.next_page, tags: params[:tags] %>');
```

Comment: You'd break endless scroll if you scroll while a tag is selected, right?

Comment: You are right. I'm editing the answer to not break the endless.

Comment: This solves the issue of "html vs append", but the tag needs to be passed to the posts_path for endless continue to work. And at time its fired for endless, there is no params[:tags]

Comment: Updated the answer to send the tags

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best way would be to implement that posts_tagged_with action so that you can keep track of which tags are selected and endless_scroll as usual (using append) with those tags. Then when another tag is selected you can replace the contents with the new collection using jquery's html method.

Comment: The problem is the endless scroll will still call the index action and add more posts that are not tagged

Comment: You have to post your endless js code. It needs to be modified to post to the correct action and include the selected tags